# Sorting an array through my method error Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, runtime-error, subsequence

I am new to programming and I need some help. I am supposed to make my own method checking if one array has a subsequence to another one. Meaning if the first array is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and the second one is {1, 2, 3} the second one is a subsequence of the first. However if the first is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and the second is {1, 4, 5} it is not a subsequence, so the second has to be in order as well.

I have tried to do it this way through strings:

```
private static boolean subs(int[] array, int[] subsequence) {
    String a = Arrays.toString(array);
    String b = Arrays.toString(subsequence);
    boolean c = false;

    if (a.equals(b)) {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if (!(b.equals(a.substring(i, b.length() + i)))) {
            c = false;
        } else {
            c = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (c == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However I get 3 errors, here is the printscreen :

[image]

And here is how I am testing the method:

```
    int[] fArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] tempArray = { 2, 3, 4 };
    System.out.println(subs(fArray, tempArray));
```

I know I probably made a lot of mistakes, so hit me with it.

Comment: Please post errors in question, no external link.  Have you stepped through code in the debugger?  Exception is quite clear, you are exceeding the bounds of a string index.  So, "b.length() + i" is most likely the problem.

Comment: Why don't you compare the integer arrays directly, instead of converting them to strings?

Comment: Because I suck at arrays, and it was just an interesting idea so I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
  if (!(b.equals(a.substring(i, b.length() + i)))) {
```

Your outer loop condition makes sure that i stays smaller than a.length().
But then you try to take a substring within a that goes for b.length()+i!

In other words: for any b.length() > 0 ... that code will **always** try to fetch characters **beyond** the end of a.

And there is also a bug in your result handling - it seems very much possible that you assign

```
c = true;
```

at some point; to later **overwrite** that with

```
c = false;
```

In other words: your code *forgets* that he found a match! The much easier solution: when hitting the true case, just return true there! And if you don't return within the loop; you just return false in the end.

Finally: although it seems like a cool idea to turn your arrays into strings ... that doesn't really buy you anything. You are still doing the work of going through the first array and checking if the second is in there. Writing code that does that **directly** on the provided arrays ... would not be much different from what you got there with your "string detour".

Edit: when using multiple returns in a method, you simply have to make sure that **any** possible path has a return statement. In your case:

```
boolean subs(... {

   if equal strings
     return true

   for i as index in a
      if a.substring equals b
        return true

   return false
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I understood where the problem was the reason I did it with strings is because I suck at arrays for now at least. I did not quite understand how to hit return after the true case since the true case is in the loop and the method does not recognize the return.

Comment: Thank you for the quick accept. I updated the answer with some pseudo code to show you how multiple returns could work. The key point is: this is only possible when all paths through that method contain a return statement. I guess *the method does not recognize the return* translates to: your code is missing some other return in another place!

Comment: After some struggle I figured it out thank you. By the way I did not know that all paths had to have return statements in order for it to work so I learned something new today. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that **fArray** as String has more chars than **tempArray** as string, so when you start to compare char by char from **a** to **b**, is a given point where the index is going beyond the size of **b** and then you get the exception

Comment: But since I put tempArray in the testing to be {2, 3, 4} i thought it would find it to be true and then break the loop and finish the method.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem line is: `if (!(b.equals(a.substring(i, b.length() + i))))`

**Why?**

Lets assume your `a.length()` is equals `6` and `b.length()` is equals `2` now your looping `for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)` with `i` going from `0 to 5`.

Now lets say your loop executed 3 times and `i is equals 4`now.
Now when you call `a.substring(4, b.length() + 4)` with `b.length() == 2` => `a.substring(4, 6)` but your string only goes from `0 to 5`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to use [`Collections.indexOfSubList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#indexOfSubList-java.util.List-java.util.List-):

```
private static boolean subs(int[] array, int[] subsequence) {
    return Collections.indexOfSubList(toList(array), toList(subsequence)) >= 0;
}

private static List<Integer> toList(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
    for (int num : array) {
        list.add(num);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//*******************************************************************
// NOTE: please read the 'More Info' tab to the right for shortcuts.
//*******************************************************************

import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class
import java.util.Arrays;
// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   int[] fArray = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int[] tempArray = { 2,3,4 };
    System.out.println(subs(fArray, tempArray));
  }
  private static boolean subs(int[] array, int[] subsequence) {
    String a = Arrays.toString(array);
    String b = Arrays.toString(subsequence);
    boolean c = false;

    if (a.equals(b)) {
        return true;
    }
    String ss = b.substring(1,b.length()-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      String substr =a.substring(i, ss.length()+i);
        if (!(ss.equals( substr ))) {
          System.out.println("heelllo");
            c = false;
        } else {
            c = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (c == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is well tested solution to the problem.